# How to make sure all lines are executed before function return

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await

Calling the readCSV from index.js

```
const productIds = await readCSV();
```

in another file:

```
async function readCSV() {
        const filepath = path.resolve('src/input_csv.csv');
        const readstream = await fs.createReadStream(filepath);
        const stream = await readstream.pipe(parser());
        let productIds = [];
        await stream.on('data', data => {
            productIds.push(data.SourceProductId);
            console.log('SourceProductId', data.SourceProductId);
        });
        await stream.on('end', () => {
            console.log(productIds);
        });
        if (productIds.length > 0) return productIds;
        else return 'no products found';
    });
}
```

it is giving the output:

```
in main: []
SourceProductId 1000050429
SourceProductId 1132353
SourceProductId 999915195
SourceProductId 50162873
SourceProductId 1000661087
[ '1000050429', '1132353', '999915195', '50162873', '1000661087' ]
```

I'm expecting the function to return an array of all values read from CSV. but the seems like it is returning before executing the `stream.on` statement.  How to make sure all lines are executed before returning. I placed await before every statement but no luck

Comment: `async/await` only works with Promise-like objects. Streams are not like that. You need to learn about Promises before scattering `await` keyword all over your code. For example `await fs.createReadStream(filepath)` what are you trying to "await" for here?

Comment: how to make sure stream done before returning?

Comment: I have added those as part of debugging now I have removed those.

Comment: You need to create a Promise that will be resolved on stream end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`stream.on` doesn't return a promise, so you cannot `await` it.

You can work around this by returning a promise from your `readCSV` function:

```
function readCSV() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        const filepath = path.resolve('src/input_csv.csv');
        const readstream = fs.createReadStream(filepath);
        const stream = readstream.pipe(parser());
        let productIds = [];
        stream.on('data', data => {
            productIds.push(data.SourceProductId);
            console.log('SourceProductId', data.SourceProductId);
        });
        stream.on('end', () => {
            console.log(productIds);
            if (productIds.length > 0) resolve(productIds);
            else resolve('no products found');
        });

    });
}
```

You create a promise by passing a callback function as argument. That callback function gets an argument `resolve`, which is a another callback function that you call when your asynchronous operation is done, passing the result.

In the example above, we call this `resolve` callback with the product IDs after the file read stream has finished.

Since `readCSV` now returns a promise, you can `await` it like you did in your code example:

```
const productIds = await readCSV();
```

Comment: I've added some explanation to make it clear what's going on